# Enable Codeigniter's XSS filtering without losing style tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE and am trying to get indentation and centering to work.

Here is my initialization:

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#body',
    });
</script>

<textarea id="body" name="body"></textarea>
```

When I indent the text it works on the front-end however here is what I find in the database:

```
<div [removed] center;">
```

When I reload the page and it pulls the text it is not centered/indented.

Can anybody help? Thanks.

**Edit:** After further inspection, Codeigniter seems to be removing the inline styles using XSS filtering.

This: `$this->input->post('body')`

Instead of: `$this->input->post('body', TRUE)`

fixed the issue. However, I need XSS filtering. Is there any way to keep XSS filtering but not lose the style tags?

Comment: That would lead me to believe your back end code is removing that style.  Are you running the code through any validator?

Comment: Yep! I just posted an edit.

Comment: Please update your post's title and tags to reflect this is a CodeIgniter issue - this is not due to anything TinyMCE is doing.